# Both override and mixin a class

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding, mixins

Is it possible to both override and mixin a class?

I tried applying the mixin inside the constructor, but it is not adding he properties/functions to the override.

I thought mixins were implicitly applied to the class referring to them?

#### Mixin

```
Ext.define('App.mixins.VTypes', {
    //extend: 'Ext.mixin.Mixin',   

    timeTest : /^([1-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\s[a|p]m)$/i,

    time: function(v, field) { return this.timeTest.test(v); },
    timeText: 'Not a valid time.  Must be in the format "12:34 PM".',
    timeMask: /[\d\s:amp]/i
});
```

#### Override

```
Ext.define('App.overrides.VTypes', {
    override : 'Ext.form.field.VTypes',
    mixins : {
        vtypes : 'App.mixins.VTypes'
    },

    IPAddressTest : /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/,

    IPAddress:  function(v) { return this.IPAddressTest.test(v); },
    IPAddressText: 'Must be a numeric IP address, for eg: 111.1.1.1',
    IPAddressMask: /[\d\.]/i,

    constructor : function() {
        Ext.apply(this, this.mixins.vtypes);

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Here's the [**Sencha Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1vo6&view/editor) I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply a mixin to `Ext.form.field.VTypes` easily. In fact, your constructor never gets called (Take a look at the source code of `Ext.form.field.VTypes`). Additionally, `Ext.form.field.VTypes` is defined as a singleton.

The definition of `Ext.form.field.VTypes` looks very different to a class definition for e.g. a GridPanel. It behaves more like a pure JS "class" definition, thus your mixin gets never applied as it would for a "normal" ExtJS class.

Nevertheless, you can easily simulate a mixin behavior by your own:

```
var ip = {
    IPAddressTest : /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/,
    IPAddress:  function(v) { return this.IPAddressTest.test(v); },
    IPAddressText: 'Must be a numeric IP address, for eg: 111.1.1.1',
    IPAddressMask: /[\d\.]/i
 };

var time = {
    timeTest : /^([1-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\s[a|p]m)$/i,
    time: function(v, field) { return this.timeTest.test(v); },
    timeText: 'Not a valid time.  Must be in the format "12:34 PM".',
    timeMask: /[\d\s:amp]/i
};


Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, ip);
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, time);
```

Here, you spare the override and just apply the object definition to the `Ext.form.field.VTypes` singleton. I think, doing it that way is even more readable and understandable (but that's just my opinion).

Comment: The problem with this is I have two applications that share common VTypes. One application will override and add its own validation functions.The files are loaded via the Application and views. Not sure how this will work? Apply it in the Application layer?

Comment: Since vtypes is a singleton it should not matter where you do it.